# Python numpy array из обычного итератора

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть датафрэйм, мне надо сделать по нему сложную итерацию, т.е. итерацию со своей логикой.

Я написал стандартный итератор, ну который с методом **next**
. Но, после этого выяснилось, что модель не понимает стандартных итераторов, и требует на вход numpy.array.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно эмулировать numpy.array из обычного итератора ?

Comment: Что-то как-то путано вы объяснили. Что такое "модель"? Можете привести код? Или хотя бы по пунктам распишите, что откуда у вас получается, и где именно возникла заминка.

Comment: А как он понимает, что это numpy.array? Проверки типов нет. И у него нет таких уж особых функций

Comment: есть файл с данными, я его читаю в pandas.DataFrame. Мне нужно из него сформировать массив массивов по сложной логике. Для этого я сделал итератор. Дальше этот массив массивов нужно запихнуть в модель keras. Но модель понимает только numpy.array. Создавать numpy.array и копировать в него данные, не хочется, так как данных будет очень много. Чтоб обойти эту проблему я хочу сделать некий класс, который будет "выглядеть" как numpy.array и подсунуть его в модель. Для этого, предположительно, нужно использовать numpy.nditer.

Comment: Понимает проверкой наличия поля shape

Comment: Создайте поле shape

Comment: @PetrStukalov, может стоит задать вопрос о "сложной итерации" по DataFrame? Как показывает практика 95% задач в Pandas решаются векторизированным способом (т.е. без итерирования)...

Comment: вобще да. но нужен механизм согласования формата датафрэйма и модели. может пото и получится оптимизировать, но пока идей на эту тему нет....

Comment: `np.array(list(your_iterator))` - должно помочь, но это неправильный подход...

Comment: @MaxU, неправильный т.к. будет копировать данные ? Или потому, что не соответствует стилю языка ?

Comment: @PetrStukalov, столбцы DataFrame это уже `Numpy array`, поэтому если найти решение в стиле Pandas (без итерирования), то можно скармливать Keras столбцы DataFrame'а как таковые - т.е. без копирования/создания новых и т.д.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, создал. не проходит проверка на этого шейпа. что то я делаю совсем не так...

Comment: @MaxU, вот смотрите. мне нужно пройти по окном длинной несколько сотен строк, по датафрейму. каждое состояние окна нужно скормить в модель. модель принимает обучающие данные только в начале, все сразу, массив массивов. как это сделать правильно ?

Comment: Имитация атрибута `shape` может помочь пройти только одну единственную проверку - дальше понадобиться имплементировать все методы Numpy которые используются (дергаются)... ;)

Comment: @MaxU, что то мне не хочется писать полную реализацию numpy.array

Comment: @PetrStukalov, задайте соответствующий вопрос с небольшим примером входных данных, функцией (попытки будет достаточно) обработки окна и ожидаемым результатом. Тогда мы хотя бы сможем попытаться помочь... А так - жто слишком общий вопрос, на который можно дать только общий ответ - например воспользоваться `rolling window` в Pandas

Comment: Ладно, всем огромное спасибо. Буду искать более оптимальный подход с другой стороны.  Похоже, я все делаю не так, как надо делать именно в питоне.